# Настройка цвета для сводной таблицы

Tags: таблицы

Есть сводная таблица,  построенная по формату строки с атрибутом "Услуга", столбцы в формате "месяц" (от 1 до 12) -> "просрочка" (не просрочен/просрочен) и показателем "количество заявок".
Есть ли возможность настроить цвета исключительно для столбца "просрочка" с значение "просрочен" всё, что больше 5% подсвечивать красным цветом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть если смотреть пример, то в 1 строке 5 месяц значение "просрочен" должна быть красной.

---

Версия OBIEE 12c